# GraphicsMagick performance issue using c++ java native code

Tags: java, c++, tomcat, java-native-interface, graphicsmagick

I am using GraphicsMagick C++ api and calling it in a java web project which is deployed on tomcat to resize images dynamically on runtime from a certain size to given width/height. I am using scale() method of C++ api.

Now the performance is normal when there is not much load on tomcat but when number of connections/load increases on server the performance of Image resizing declines greatly. Even it goes to 30 to 40 seconds on each resize. Although memory , cpu and io utilization of the system seems normal and not bad at all.

Can any one help me with this issue? I would be highly grateful

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen this from the [Graphics Magick documentation](http://www.graphicsmagick.org/convert.html)?

gm convert -size 120x120 cockatoo.jpg -resize 120x120 +profile "*" thumbnail.jpg

In this example, '-size 120x120' gives a hint to the JPEG decoder that the image is going to be downscaled to 120x120, allowing it to run faster by avoiding returning full-resolution images to GraphicsMagick for the subsequent resizing operation. The '-resize 120x120' specifies the desired dimensions of the output image. It will be scaled so its largest dimension is 120 pixels. The '+profile "*"' removes any ICM, EXIF, IPTC, or other profiles that might be present in the input and aren't needed in the thumbnail.

If you aren't currently using the size option, you might notice a big difference.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this when we were having similar problem. But now we have a good solution to this. Try out gm4java + im4java:
http://kennethxu.blogspot.com/2013/04/integrate-java-and-graphicsmagick.html